# How to Search Tickets Using Dynamic Field In OTRS 5 - Rest

Tags: rest, otrs

I'm stuck on how to search all tickets by `Dynamic Field`.

Comment: Erm, once the chat has been trimmed from your question, there is not really anything left (that you are stuck or that you have been searching for days are not all that useful to readers). May we see your last attempt? Do you have some code at present? What language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the API this way:

```
my @TicketIDs = $TicketObject->TicketSearch(
  Result => 'ARRAY',

  # DynamicFields
  #   At least one operator must be specified. Operators will be connected with AND,
  #       values in an operator with OR.
  #   You can also pass more than one argument to an operator: ['value1', 'value2']
  DynamicField_FieldNameOfYourDynamicField => {
    Equals            => 123,
    Like              => 'value*',                # "equals" operator with wildcard support
    GreaterThan       => '2017-01-01 01:01:01',
    GreaterThanEquals => '2017-01-01 01:01:01',
    SmallerThan       => '2020-02-02 02:02:02',
    SmallerThanEquals => '2020-02-02 02:02:02',
  }

  # user search (UserID is required)
  UserID     => 123,
  Permission => 'ro' || 'rw',
);
```